# How to test enzyme components that render into the top level

Tags: javascript, enzyme, grommet

I'm trying to test a component that renders a [grommet](https://github.com/grommet/grommet) `Menu` component. The grommet`Menu` component renders an absolutely positioned menu into the top level of the document, inserted as a child to `body`. Therefore it renders outside the scope of the wrapper. I can find it with `document.body.innerHTML` (referencing jsdom document) but I want to interact with it using enzyme. Any recommendations?

My Test:

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <MyComponent checkThis={checkThisSpy} />
);
wrapper.find('.spec-menu').simulate('click');
console.log(document.body.innerHTML); // Shows the absolute menu inserted into the body
```

The line in grommet that does this `document.body.insertBefore(drop.container, document.body.firstChild);`. https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/master/src/js/utils/Drop.js#L197

Just looking for some guidance on the best way to handle this. Thanks!

Comment: Is the menu rendered by the grommet component another child component? If not its an element that is just appended to the dom right? In this case I think you could use something like  chai-dom to verify that that the inner html element exists in the fake document element. http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-dom/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, we weren't able to find any way to test that the component using enzyme itself. Because we're using jsdom to provide the dom, `document` is globally available. We ended up writing some expectations that look like

```
expect(document.getElementsByClassName('my-top-level')).to.have.length(1)
```

The normal dom API is sufficient to test everything we want, it's just a little clunkier.